# Laravel 4.2 and Beanstalkd: Error sending queued mail

Tags: php, email, laravel-4, queue, beanstalkd

I'm trying to send emails with queues using Laravel 4.2, beanstalkd and mandrill via Forge/DigitalOcean.

Everything runs perfectly async, the Queue runs until it tries to send the mail with Mail::send() it fails with this error:

```
Undefined index: HTTP_ORIGIN (View: /home/forge/default/app/views/emails/campaign.blade.php)
```

That php file is the view (emails/campaign) sent to the Mail method.

```
Mail::send('emails/campaign', 
            array('campaignView' => $campaignView), 
            function($mail) use($campaign) {
                $mail->to($campaign->email, "{$campaign->name} {$campaign->last}")
                     ->subject($campaign->title)
                     ->from($campaign->email, $campaign->remitent)
                     ->replyTo($campaign->answer);
});
```

Note that i'm managing the queues with Queue::push(), that's why I'm not using Mail::queue().

I'm so lost now and don't know what is happening here..

Any ideas?